# How to improve seo for keyword to achieve it from 9th to top 3 result in google's first page

Tags: seo, keywords

I have one keyword for my site and when I search for it , it is displaying my website at 9th result in first page in Google , Now I want to know that what improvement I need to do in SEO for same keyword to reach in top 3 result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so many parameters Google uses to rank websites that it's impossible to tell you at the moment what to do next. Things like website speed (time taken to load the pages), server location, whether your site is served using HTTP or HTTPS, all aparently make a difference. The rankings change regularly too, as Google says it looks for "fresh" content.

However, if you build a website that does the basics well then there is nothing stopping the site ranking better naturally. I wouldn't get bogged down with the latest fads and cool tricks. Build your website and write your content for your target audience, not for Google.

Comment: I see...thank you for helpful answer but I have many time observed that if we see our site in top 10 by specific keyword and after that for sometime if we do not do anything then result for same keyword put our site to 2nd or 3rd page , So do I need to change content to maintain position? My goal is at least maintain position in top 10..

Comment: One up-vote for at least the last paragraph. I have been talking about making your SEO strategy about the content first. I have seen really ugly and simple sites rank well for decades simply because the content is outstanding. If a site's speed is within a good/normal range, making it faster will not do much. Google grades site speed on a curve. As well, changing from HTTP to HTTPS only ups one small set of trust metrics which can be easily trumped with other trust metrics- the interruption making the change would be too great. I use semantics for increasing position for terms these days.